# How to simulate real uniswap v2 slippage without actually send transaction?

Tags: web3js, cryptocurrency

Some `erc20` tokens will burn percentage of tokens as tax on transaction. In this situation, a dry call using Web3.eth.Contract with proper `minAmountOut` of `swapExactETHForTokens` will not be reverted even token recieved will be significantly smaller than `minAmountOut`. But uniswap, pancake and many other dex tools can successfully simulate this behavior, and show `PancakeRouter: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT` accordingly.

By the way, I'm relying on metamask for the call.

Answer (score 0):

I find out there is an `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` to do that.